# How do I remove a ring that is stuck on my finger?

Tags: personal-care

I've tried everything to get the ring off my finger and now my finger is too fat.

I tried soap, string and lotion to remove it.

Comment: search for "how to remove a ring with dental floss" on youtube

Comment: Get on an air-plane, the reduction in pressure causes your fingers to contract. I actually lost a ring this way!

Comment: Use windex - that’s what they do at the jewelry shop in my neighborhood

Comment: I've done the dental floss trick that @CraigConstantine mentioned and it works great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Submerge your hand in ice water for a bit; not so long that you suffer any damage from the cold, but long enough that your fingers will shrink a bit. With your hand still in the water, try working the ring off of it. It's likely that, when cold, your finger will be narrow enough now to work the ring free (you can try adding a little oil to your finger above the ring prior to soaking it if you feel you'll need a little extra help).

If the ring is too tight to remove via this process, it's dangerously tight, and you'll have to seek professional help to have it cut free.

Comment: Done this myself and it works.

Answer (score -1):

The most reliable method is to cut the ring, allowing you to bend it open enough to get it off.  I had to do this several years ago with a ring I'd worn for about fifteen years.

Now, doing this yourself isn't easy, especially if the ring is on your dominant hand (mine, fortunately, wasn't), so you may need to enlist a friend you trust.  A jeweler's saw or rotary tool with cutting disc will do the job; a vise to hold the ring (allowing you to push your finger away from the tool in use) and a piece of cut soda can slipped inside between finger and tools will both help, depending what's available.

If the ring is very valuable, or a family heirloom, or similar, you may want to look into losing a lot of weight...

Comment: This DIY effort is mostly a good way to slice up your hand.

Comment: I suggest it because I've done it, myself, without help and without injury.  It requires some care, and tools that you can control (a file and jeweler's saw are safer than, say, an angle grinder, obviously).

Comment: self amputation is a bit extreme.